# Restart PowerPoint Presentation by a Macro

Tags: vba, powerpoint

The Powerpoint-Presentation is running on two devices at the same time. So one of the presenations is in read-only mode.
I would like to have a macro, which updates the presentation in read-only-mode, so the changes on the presentation (write-mode) are applied.
The macro will be started manually by a button.

I already tried to write a macro that restarts the presentation, but wasn't successfull.

```
Sub Prog()

Dim DestinationPPT As String
Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation

Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
DestinationPPT = "xxx.ppsm"

Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)

myPresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run

Application.Quit

End Sub
```

Seems like the command `Application.Quit` is closing both presentations that are opened.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close a certain file and not the whole application.

```
Dim PPTFile As Object
Set PPTFile = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application").Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)
PPTFile.Close
```

Use `File.Close` instead of `Application.Quit`

I hope this helped.